# How to pass several values as nosetests' options in setup.cfg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I currently run my tests with :

```
nosetests3 -vd -w . module1 module2
```

...And I would like to automate these options.

However, I can't find a way to pass several values to an option...

I tried this :

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=1
detailed-errors=1
where=.
   module1
   module2
```

...But it replies

```
ValueError: Working directory '.
module1
module2' not found, or not a directory
```

and with :

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=1
detailed-errors=1
where=.
where=module1
where=module2
```

it replies :

```
nosetests: error: Error reading config file 'setup.cfg': While reading from 'setup.cfg' [line  6]: option 'where' in section 'nosetests' already exists
```

how to do that ?